# How to check for the version number?

Tags: lua, version, lua-4.0

I've written a small program in Lua 4. In the output it produces I have the program version number stored as a string as follows:

```
AppVersion = "1.6.2"
```

How do I parse this string to check whether the recorded version number is equal to or less than the current program version number?

Comment: If the version strings only contain single-digit fields as in the example, ordinary string comparison works just fine: `AppVersion <= recordedVersion`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
AppVersion = "1.6.2"
recordedVersion = "1.7.2"

_, _, v1, v2, v3 = strfind( AppVersion, "(%d+)%.(%d+)%.(%d+)" )
_, _, r1, r2, r3 = strfind( recordedVersion, "(%d+)%.(%d+)%.(%d+)" )
```

(The relevant section of the manual is [here](http://www.lua.org/manual/4.0/manual.html#6.2)).

Then you can convert the three components of each version to numbers and compare them.

Answer (score 3):

For Lua 5.1 I ended up using the below code:

```lua
AppVersion = "1.6.2"
local major, minor, patch = string.match(AppVersion, "(%d+)%.(%d+)%.(%d+)")
```